# How could I change the duration of zoomToRect in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I tried the following code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0,options:.BeginFromCurrentState, animations:{
        self.scrollView.zoomToRect(CGRectMake(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY),
                                   animated: false)
       }, 
       completion: nil)
```

The duration of `zoomToRect` is still default time(too fast.) Is there any way I could change it?

Comment: have you tried setting delay parameter?

Comment: @UmangBista I tried it, still no changes